# Android - switching between listviews without changing the layout?

Tags: java, android, listview, viewswitcher

I'm not looking for exact code here, just a direction on what to look for and what I should be reading about so I can figure this out.

I have a layout that I would like to remain static, with only the listview changing depending on what's selected from the list.  I've reloaded data in the list, but I would like the fancy transition animations between choices, and would like the app to go to the previous menu when pressing back.

Someone suggested using a viewswitcher, which seems like it'd be great, but I am still unsure about how to fill a listview in a layout with a regular row layout, then on selection do an animated transition to a custom row.  Also, it seems the viewswitcher is limited to two views, so it may be a limitation when I want to go a few menus deeper.

Preferably, I'd like to put each menu in it's own class so that I can handle filling it in that class, if possible...

Hope this isn't too vague, but if it is I'll be more than happy to explain myself further.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's what you meant but have you tried showing and hiding the views?

```
findViewById(R.id.listViewID).setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE); //hide the one you want
findViewById(R.id.listViewID2).setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE); //show the one you want
```

Hope it's what you meant :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I'm not sure that will help with using transition animations between menus.

Let's say I have an XML layout that includes a listview, how could I ONLY change the listview portion of the layout while keeping the rest of the layout static, and incorporate animations when switching to the new listview?

Comment: It would work fine with animation.  Whatever method you called the .setVisibility in could also call your animation methods.

Comment: agree with user432209 regarding the animation.
R.id.ListViewID -> replace ListViewID with the id of the portion you want to show/hide.